# Disable Tab Item's(Storyboard) in IOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I am using TabController in Storyboard Control. After user logged in to aPP, TABController get loaded with 5 TAB.

when use click on button on tab 1, I wanted to disabled rest 4 tab's. There should not be any User interaction to another 4 TAB's.

below is simple code, but it does not disable other 4 tabs:

```
-(void)tab_Dis:(Bool)bOpen
{
   UITabBarController *about_vc = (UITabBarController*)[[UIStoryboard      storyboardWithName:@"NexTabBar" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ID_TABBAR"];
   UITabBar *tabBar = about_vc.tabBar;

   if(bOpen)
   {
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setEnabled:FALSE];
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setEnabled:FALSE];
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setEnabled:FALSE];
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setEnabled:FALSE];
   }
   else
   {
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setEnabled:TRUE];
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setEnabled:TRUE];
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setEnabled:TRUE];
      [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setEnabled:TRUE];
   }
}
```

but even if setEnabled is FALSE i can click on another tabs..
   what is the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try the answer stated in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484124/5334132.

Comment: i do not want to disable entire tab controller, except current tab-Item rest all tabs i wanted to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, below is the code working fine:

```
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setEnabled:FALSE];
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setEnabled:FALSE];
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3] setEnabled:FALSE];
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:4] setEnabled:FALSE];
```